# Sending data from one session to multiple session

Tags: c#

I am facing some problem  in session,actually i want to send some session information to all session suppose for ex i am putting some value in one text-box for customer(like body weight) and i want to maintain that session value for all other session.

Comment: Make at least a bit of effort.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Are you trying to create a chat system?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what you're trying to ask..

Comment: actually in my project i want to put some athletic information like weight,height,etc. if we put these information in text-box and these information is maintain through out till session end in different page.

Comment: and we need not to put it again when we move to put some other information in next page.

Comment: i am putting some information in my text-box like athletic weight,height,etc  and I want that this information is maintain in text-box when we move to next page or to next session and we need not to put it again and again when we move on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then for example to save the information:

```
this.Session["Weight"] = txtWeight.Text;
```

then to retrieve:

```
string weight = this.Session["Weight"];
```